# Don't know how to adjust space between rows and handle overflow

Tags: tables

```
\documentclass[a4paper,svgnames,11pt]{article}

\textheight = 220mm
\textwidth = 150mm
\topmargin = 10mm
\oddsidemargin = 5.0mm
\evensidemargin = 5.0mm
\unitlength = 1mm

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\pagenumbering{Roman}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages} 

\begin{document}

\begin{flushleft}
\begin{tabular}{l l}
        \textbf{Value}  &  \\
        \textbf{Keywords}  &  \textit{Artificial intelligence, machine learning, humans, decentralization}    \\
        \textbf{Paper type}  & Hybrid research paper. \\
\end{tabular}
\end{flushleft}

\end{document}
```

**Current result:**
[image]

**Desire:**
Add more space between, and fix so that, if more keywords are appended, so that it doesn't overflow.

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/134805), instead of a code snippet.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos, I have posted the screenshot. That's how it looks.

Comment: I wrote about the LaTeX code, not about what it creates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- To increase the distance between lines, use

  ```
  \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.3}
  ```

  Best enclose it, together with the tabular, in a group, to limit the effect of the `\renewcommand`
- The package `tabularx` contributes the column specifier `X`, which distributes all space left by columns of other types between `X` columns. Additionally, `X` columns typeset the text in paragraph mode such that the lines do not overflow at the right border. Without `tabularx`, you can use `p{width}` columns.
- The `@{}` specifier removes the extra space at the left and right of the table, such that it is flush left (and right) with the borders.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}
\noindent
{\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.3}%
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}lX@{}}
        \textbf{Value}  &  \\
        \textbf{Keywords}  &  \textit{Artificial intelligence, machine learning, humans, decentralization, machines, and more, and more, and more}    \\
        \textbf{Paper type}  & Hybrid research paper. \\
\end{tabularx}%
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thx. I am noticing the overflow problem.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution with the new `tabularray` package ([CTAN](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tabularray)).

```
\documentclass[a4paper,svgnames,11pt]{article}

\textheight = 220mm
\textwidth = 150mm
\topmargin = 10mm
\oddsidemargin = 5.0mm
\evensidemargin = 5.0mm
\unitlength = 1mm

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\pagenumbering{Roman}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}

\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\begin{flushleft}
    \begin{tblr}{
            colspec={lX}, % X column type uses all available space
            column{1}={font=\bfseries}, % first column bold
        }
        Value  &  \\
        Keywords  & \textit{Artificial intelligence, machine learning, humans, decentralization} \\
        Long Text & This is some really long text which doesn't fit on a single line. It will automatically flow over several lines. \\
        Paper type & Hybrid research paper. \\
    \end{tblr}
\end{flushleft}

\end{document}
```

[image: output table]

This has more vertical spacing by default. If you want to increase that further, you can play around with the `rowsep` key. You can also specify `\bfseries` for the whole column, so you don't have to write `\textbf` for every cell.